# Discrete time kalman filter with augmented state vector

Tags: matlab, kalman-filter

I am trying to implement the discrete time kalman filter for a state space model with an augmented state vector. That is, the *state equation* is given by:

**x**(t) = 0.80**x**(t-1) + **noise**

There is only latent process in my example so the **x**(t) is of dimension 1x1. The measurement equation is given by:

**Y**(t) = A**X**(t) + **noise**

Where capital **Y**(t) has dimension 3x1. It contains three observed series, **Y**(t) = [**y1**(t),**y2**(t),**y3**(t)]'. Two of the observed series are occasionally missing in a systematic way:

- **y1**(t) is observed at all time points.
- **y2**(t) is observed at every fourth time point.
- **y3**(t) is observed at every twelfth time point.

The dimension of the measurement matrix **A** is 3x12 and the dimension of capital **X**(t) is 12x1. This is a vector stacked with the last twelve realizations of the latent process:

**X**(t) = [**x**(t),**x**(t-1),...,**x**(t-11)]'.

The reason for capital **X**(t) being stacked is that **y1**(t) is related to **x**(t) and **x**(t-1). Moreover, **y2**(t) is related to **x**(t), **x**(t-1), **x**(t-2) and **x**(t-3). Finally, **y3**(t) is related to all of the last twelve realizations of the latent process.

The attached matlab code simulates data from this state space model and subsequently runs through a kalman filter with an augmented state space vector, **X**(t).

**My problem is**, that the filtered (and the predicted) process differs substantially from the true latent process. This can be seen from the attached figure as well. Clearly, I am doing something wrong but I am unable to see what it is? My kalman filter worked very well, when the state vector was not stacked... I hope someone can help, thanks![image]

```
    %-------------------------------------- %
    % AUGMENTED KALMAN FILTER WITH MISSINGS
    % ------------------------------------- %

    clear; close all; clc;

    % 1) SET PARAMETER VALUES %
    % ----------------------- %

    % Number of observations, number of latent processes and observed
    % processes.
    T = 2000;
    NumberOfLatent = 1;
    NumberOfObs = 3;

    % Measurement Matrix, A.
    A = [-0.40, -0.15, zeros(1,10);
          0.25,  0.25, 0.25, 0.25, zeros(1,8);
         ones(1,12)];

    % State transition matrix, Phi. 
    Phi = zeros(12,12);
    Phi(1,1) = 0.80;
    Phi(2:end,1:end-1) = eye(11);

    % Covariance matrix (for the measurement equation).            
    R = diag([2.25; 1.00; 1.00]);

    % State noise and measurement noise.
    MeasNoise = mvnrnd(zeros(1,NumberOfObs),R,T)';
    StateNoise = randn(NumberOfLatent,T+11);

    % One latent process (X) and three observed processes (Y).
    X = zeros(NumberOfObs,T+11);  
    Y = zeros(NumberOfObs,T); 

    % Set initial state.
    X0 = 0;

    % 2) SIMULATE DATA %
    % ---------------- %
    % Before Y (the observed processes) can be simulated we need to simulate 11
    % realisations of X (the latent process).  
    for t = 1:T+11
       if (t == 1)
            X(:,t) = Phi(1,1)*X0 + StateNoise(:,t);
       else
            X(:,t) = Phi(1,1)*X(1,t-1) + StateNoise(:,t);
       end
       if (t>=12)
            Y(:,t-11) = A*X(1,t:-1:t-11)' + MeasNoise(:,t-11);
       end
    end


    % 3) DELETE DATA SUCH THAT THERE ARE MISSINGS %
    % ------------------------------------------- %
    % First row is observed at all time points. The second rows is observed  at
    % every 4th. time point and the third row is observed at every 12th. time
    % point.
    for j = 1:3
        Y(2,j:4:end) = NaN;
    end
    for j = 1:11
        Y(3,j:12:end) = NaN;
    end


    % 4) RUN THE KALMAN FILTER WITH AUGMENTED STATE VECTOR %
    % ---------------------------------------------------- %

    % Initializing matrices.
    AugmentedStates = 12;
    X_predicted = zeros(AugmentedStates,T);                   % Predicted  states.
    X_filtered = zeros(AugmentedStates,T);            % Updated states.
    P_predicted = zeros(AugmentedStates,AugmentedStates,T);   % Predicted variances.
    P_filtered = zeros(AugmentedStates,AugmentedStates,T);   % Filtered variances.
    KG = zeros(AugmentedStates,NumberOfObs,T);       % Kalman gains.
    Q  = eye(AugmentedStates);                       % State noise for  augmented states.
    Res         = zeros(NumberOfObs,T);                       % Residuals.

    % Initial values:
    X_zero = ones(AugmentedStates,1);
    P_zero = eye(AugmentedStates);

    for t = 1:T

        % Initialisation of the Kalman filter.
        if (t == 1)
            X_predicted(:,t) = Phi * X_zero;                          %  Initial predicted state, dimension (AugmentedStates x 1).
            P_predicted(:,:,t) = Phi * P_zero * Phi'+ Q;              % Initial variance, dimension (AugmentedStates x AugmentedStates).
        else
         % #1 Prediction step.
           X_predicted(:,t) = Phi * X_filtered(:,t-1);                    %   Predicted state, dimension (AugmentedStates x 1).
           P_predicted(:,:,t) = Phi * P_filtered(:,:,t-1) * Phi'+ Q;      % Variance of prediction, dimension (AugmentedStates x AugmentedStates).
        end

        % If there is missings the corresponding entries in A and Y is set  to
        % zero.
        if sum(isnan(Y(:,t)))>0
            temp = find(isnan(Y(:,t)));                             
            Y(temp,t) = 0;                                         
            A(temp,:) = 0;              
        end

        % #3 Calculate the Kalman Gains and save them in the matrix KG.
        K = (P_predicted(:,:,t) * A')/(A * P_predicted(:,:,t) * A' + R);         % Kalman Gains, dimension (AugmentedStates x ObservedProcesses).
        KG(:,:,t) = K;  

        % Residuals.
        Res(:,t) = Y(:,t) - A*X_predicted(:,t);                

        % #3 Update step.
        X_filtered(:,t) =  X_predicted(:,t) + K * Res(:,t);                           % Updated state (AugmentedStates x 1).
        P_filtered(:,:,t) = (eye(AugmentedStates) - K * A) * P_predicted(:,:,t);    % Updated variance, dimension (AugmentedStatesstates x AugmentedStates).

         % Measurement Matrix, A, is recreated.
         A = [-0.40, -0.15, zeros(1,10);
               0.25,  0.25, 0.25, 0.25, zeros(1,8);
               ones(1,12)];

     end
```

Comment: One bug I see:  When you erase parts of `A` due to missing observations, they are never restored.

Comment: I have corrected my question. Thanks @Ben Jackson! Unfortunately, that does not solve the problem. The big did not occur in my original script, only in this script I created for the question (unfortunately....).

Comment: This line **K = (P_predicted(:,:,t) * A')/(A * P_predicted(:,:,t) * A' + R)**; % Kalman Gains, dimension (AugmentedStates x ObservedProcesses). Attempts to add matrix of size 2x2 by a matrix of size 3x3. This is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Aha. I realized what the bug is. The state transition matrix (Phi) in the matlab code is not correct. That is, in the current matlab code it is:

```
% State transition matrix, Phi. 
Phi = zeros(12,12);
Phi(1,1) = 0.80;
Phi(2:end,1) = 1
```

And it should actually look like this:

```
% State transition matrix, Phi. 
Phi = zeros(12,12);
Phi(1,1) = 0.80;
Phi(2:end,1:end-1) = eye(11)
```

Without this adjustment the state equation in the filter does not make any sense! I have implemented this in the code. And just to show that it actually works, the plot now looks like this:

[image]

... Or at least: The performance of the filter has been improved!